# Make Postfix search LDAP group members by UID instead of DN?

Tags: email, postfix, ldap

I'm creating an e-mail server with postfix (v2.7.1 on Debian 6.0) where users and groups are stored in an LDAP server.

Users accounts works fine but I want to create e-mail aliases from group (any e-mail addressed to *groupAbc@domain.tld* would be sent to the e-mail address of each member of the *groupAbc* group).

My groups are `posixGroup` whose members are listed by a `memberUid` attribute:

```
dn: cn=groupAbc,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=tld
objectClass: CourierMailAlias
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: groupAbc
gidNumber: 1001
maildrop: groupabc@domain.tld
memberUid: john-doe
memberUid: jane-doe
```

Here is my ldap-aliases.cf:

```
# cat /etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
server_host = 127.0.0.1
version = 3
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=ldap-reader,dc=domain,dc=tld
bind_pw = SECRET
search_base = dc=domain,dc=tld
query_filter = (&(objectClass=posixGroup)(mail=%s))
result_attribute = mail
special_result_attribute = memberUid
leaf_result_attribute = mail
```

When I try to send an e-mail to I get the following errors in syslog:

```
... postfix/cleanup[6601]: warning: dict_ldap_get_values[1]: search error 34: Invalid DN syntax
... postfix/cleanup[6601]: warning: dict_ldap_lookup: Had some trouble with entries returned by search: Invalid DN syntax
... postfix/cleanup[6601]: warning: 40ACF12106E: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for groupabc@domain.tld
```

Postfix is excepting a DN in the attribute I defined with `special_result_attribute` parameter.
If I change the `memberUid` from "*john-doe*" to "*uid=john-doe,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=tld*", e-mails sent to "groupabc@domain.tld" are delivered to john-doe's e-mail address.

I'm looking for a way to make Postfix do an LDAP search of the UID stored in `memberUid` attribute.
I know it's possible on Zarafa's postfix flavour (http://doc.zarafa.com/7.0/Administrator_Manual/pt-BR/html/_ConfigureOpenLDAP.html) with options `ldap_groupmembers_attribute`, `ldap_groupmembers_attribute_type` and `ldap_groupmembers_relation_attribute` but can't find how to do it properly on standard Postfix.

Comment: I didn't see the `mail` attribute in your ldif file.

Answer (score -1):

Your ldap config is wrong. Please use:

```
server_host = 127.0.0.1
version = 3
bind = no
query_filter = (&(objectClass=posixGroup)(maildrop=%s))
result_attribute = memberUid, mail
```

You can't use "bind = yes" here - this can't work. No group can/should bind (authenticate).